# Registry Permission

Tags: wmi, registry, wmi-query

I want to retrive registry permission of the **HKLM/software/sybase**  using wmi.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/1476871/Managing-Windows-Registry-with-Scripting-Part-3.htm