# How to check permissions of a Registry Key using vbscript?

Tags: vbscript, registry

I don't want to change/set permissions,i just want to check whether user is having permission to change the registry value or not.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Possible [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4332282/registry-permission). Anyway, in the answer there you have a [link](http://www.serverwatch.com/tutorials/article.php/1476871/Managing-Windows-Registry-with-Scripting-Part-3.htm), but to simplify your coding you can do error trapping and test the result.

```
On Error Resume Next
'try to write "test"-key here...
'delete your "test"-key as well
If Err.Number <> 0 Then
    WScript.Echo "no permission"
Else
    WScript.Echo "have permission"
End If
On Error GoTo 0
```